# Checking if your comment flags have been acted upon?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, comment-flags, flag-history

Even though comment flags don't count towards your flag weight, I think it would be nice to add them into your flagging history so we can still see if they were acted upon or not. Could the flagging history be made into a dual-tab page, where by default it shows *all* of your flagging history, then with three additional tabs to select answers, questions, and comments individually.

[image: flagging-summary]

---

**Update:** Now that comment flags can be *tracked* in your flagging history, would it not make sense to also make those flags visible in your history? I don't see the point in providing statistics on your comment flags and then not be able to see what comment flags you've issued and which one have been declined, etc.

[image]

Comment: @Farseeker Even so, it would be helpful for (at least) me to be able to check comment flag status so that I can learn more about how the community works. Which comments get deleted? Which don't? How can I use this to be a better SE participant?

Comment: This is likely to be declined.  Comments are second-class citizens in the network.  That's why there is _so_ little we can do with them.  They're not going to put much work into something that they don't want us to be focusing on.