# Where can I see which comments I have flagged?

Tags: support, comments, flags

So, I found the list of posts I have flagged, in the 'flag-summary', but while it lists '# comment(s) flagged', it doesn't show the comment (or a link to it). Is there a reason for that? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Note: I searched for *comment flags*, but only found questions about the 10k tools and the flags of others. This is about my own flags.

**Edit**: In fact I recently flagged a comment that I thought was pretty rude (along the lines of "moderators X and Y are morons"). It was in a question I was not involved in myself, so it's nothing personal. The flag was declined and I wanted to take another look at it, to see if I might have been wrong about the rudeness, and to better understand what is acceptable language in SO comments. But I couldn't remember where exactly I found that comment, and was kind of surprised that the flag-summary didn't help me out there either.

Comment: Related: [Checking if your comment flags have been acted upon?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119413/checking-if-your-comment-flags-have-been-acted-upon)

Comment: I recently flagged a comment but it is still waiting for review. I went to find it again in case the flag expires before it is reviewed but there is no way to do this in so far as I can see :(

Comment: This now happens as shown in [More informative flagging history for comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180377/more-informative-flagging-history-for-comments).

Comment: @tombull89: Thanks for letting me know! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Comments are ephemeral. Once they've been deleted, only moderators can view them, and not even simply at that.