# Link to the permanent URLs of the comments whose flags got declined

Tags: feature-request, declined-flags, comment-flags

This request is similar to [Where can I see which comments I have flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135528/where-can-i-see-which-comments-i-have-flagged). Instead, in this case, I wish to get the permanent URL of exactly which comments I had flagged. You can find your old, declined comment flags on `https://SITE.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/USERID?group=4&status=3`.

The previous request apparently got resolved by this answer:

> You can't. Comments are ephemeral. Once they've been deleted, only moderators can view them, and not even simply at that.

However, **I am just asking for the permanent URL of the comment, not for the text of the comment**. If I am browsing through my flagging history - say a month later - I would want to be able to know which comments I had flagged that got declined. If a month later, that comment exists, great! If not, I would sadly move on.

I know that currently the way to do so is to click on the grey flag icon - *one by one for every comment below that post* - and it would show "You have already raised this type of flag" for the comment I had flagged. It works, but it isn't really ideal.

A simple way I think would be to just make the "declined" text to be a permalink to the comment:

[image: example entry in flag summary]